# how to create a single object based on sorted object array?

Tags: javascript

This is my input:

```js
sampleDataSet = [{
    "-1":"default",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-13T13:43:58.000Z"
  }, {
    "-2":"defaultMain",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T18:44:02.000Z"
  }, {
    "4daasdasd15sdasdasd":"test1",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T15:44:04.000Z"
  }, {
    "41dasd51asda5d1sd":"test2",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-15T13:44:06.000Z"
  }, {
    "sdadsadsad561652165":"test3",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-02-16T13:44:08.000Z"
  }]
```

I want to sort above array by created date.

after sort I can get this output:

```
sampleDataSet = [
  {
    "sdadsadsad561652165": "test3",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-02-16T13:44:08.000Z"
  }{
    "-1": "default",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-03-13T13:43:58.000Z"
  },
  {
    "4daasdasd15sdasdasd": "test1",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-03-14T15:44:04.000Z"
  },
  {
    "-2": "defaultMain",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-03-14T18:44:02.000Z"
  },
  {
    "41dasd51asda5d1sd": "test2",
    "CreatedDate": "2024-03-15T13:44:06.000Z"
  }
]
```

The I wanted to build single object like this

`{"sdadsadsad561652165":"test3","-1":"default","4daasdasd15sdasdasd":"test1","-2":"defaultMain","41dasd51asda5d1sd":"test2"}`

This is what I tried:

`let res = {};`

```
sampleDataSet.forEach(obj => {
 const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
 const value = obj[key];
 res[key] = value;
})
console.log(res)
```

but this what I get

`{"4daasdasd15sdasdasd":"test1","-1":"default","-2":"defaultMain","41dasd51asda5d1sd":"test2""sdadsadsad561652165":"test3"}`

Why is that happening How can I fix that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: You should _not_ rely on the order of keys in an object, as they are not required to be in any particular order. Most browsers use the same first-in-last-out system, but the spec says you cannot rely on it. Also, you are looking to make an object, so instantiate one instead of an array (so not `let res = [];` but `let res = {}`). And both objects mentioned are semantically the same, just a different 'order of keys', which will be meaningless as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array by `CreatedDate`
2. Reduce it to an object with removing `CreatedDate` with destructuring and use `Object.assign` to collect remaining item props into the final result.

Note that though it's not recommended to rely on prop order in an object the order's kinda preserved de-facto.

Except positive integers which is sorted and put first (I guess that's done for array-like objects). Or strings representing them. So make sure your integers are negative.

```js
const sampleDataSet = [{
    "-1":"default",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-13T13:43:58.000Z"
  }, {
    "-2":"defaultMain",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T18:44:02.000Z"
  }, {
    "4daasdasd15sdasdasd":"test1",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T15:44:04.000Z"
  }, {
    "41dasd51asda5d1sd":"test2",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-03-15T13:44:06.000Z"
  }, {
    "sdadsadsad561652165":"test3",
    "CreatedDate":"2024-02-16T13:44:08.000Z"
  }]

const result = sampleDataSet
  .sort(({CreatedDate: a}, {CreatedDate: b}) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0)
  .reduce((r, {CreatedDate, ...item}) => Object.assign(r, item), {});
  
console.log(result);
```

If you want sorted props with positive integers AND the same object property access syntax you could try to use `Proxy` to wrap `Map` (note that we changed negative integers to positive ones):

```js
const Obj = new Proxy(Object, {
  apply(_, __, args){
    return new Obj(...args);
  },
  construct(_, args){
    const obj = Reflect.construct(...arguments);
    const map = new Map;
    
    for(const arg of args){
      for(const key in arg){
       map.set(key, arg[key]);
      }
    }
    
    return new Proxy(obj, {
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_, prop) {
        return { configurable: true, enumerable: true, value: map.get(prop) };
      },
      ownKeys(){
         return [...map.keys()];
      },
      get(_, prop){
        if(prop === Symbol.iterator){
          return map.keys.bind(map);
        }
        if(prop in obj){
          return obj[prop];
        }
        return map.get(prop);
      },
      set(_, prop, value){
        map.set(prop, value);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }

});

    const sampleDataSet = [{
        1:"default",
        "CreatedDate":"2024-03-13T13:43:58.000Z"
      }, {
        2:"defaultMain",
        "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T18:44:02.000Z"
      }, {
        "4daasdasd15sdasdasd":"test1",
        "CreatedDate":"2024-03-14T15:44:04.000Z"
      }, {
        "41dasd51asda5d1sd":"test2",
        "CreatedDate":"2024-03-15T13:44:06.000Z"
      }, {
        "sdadsadsad561652165":"test3",
        "CreatedDate":"2024-02-16T13:44:08.000Z"
      }]

    const result = sampleDataSet
      .sort(({CreatedDate: a}, {CreatedDate: b}) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0)
      .reduce((r, {CreatedDate, ...item}) => Object.assign(r, item), Obj({}));
      
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: But again, you cannot control key order of objects which is what the OP is asking if I understand correctly, so…. Same issue.

Comment: @somethinghere when property names aren't  positive integers or string representing them the order of keys is de-facto preserved

Comment: @somethinghere also solvable with `Proxy`, i've updated the answer

Comment: Not by the actual standard. There is no guarantee of key order, and assuming or defacto-ing is a hack where you should have used other, more appropriate solutions.

Answer (score -2):

so, if you want correct order, you gotta use an array.
if you want object for accessing an element with a specific key,
here's a simple function to find it.

instead of `res["-2"]` you'll use `resGet("-2")`

```js
let sorted = [
    {
        sdadsadsad561652165: 'test3',
        CreatedDate: '2024-02-16T13:44:08.000Z',
    },
    {
        '-1': 'default',
        CreatedDate: '2024-03-13T13:43:58.000Z',
    },
    {
        '4daasdasd15sdasdasd': 'test1',
        CreatedDate: '2024-03-14T15:44:04.000Z',
    },
    {
        '-2': 'defaultMain',
        CreatedDate: '2024-03-14T18:44:02.000Z',
    },
    {
        '41dasd51asda5d1sd': 'test2',
        CreatedDate: '2024-03-15T13:44:06.000Z',
    },
]

const resGet = key => sorted.find(el=>[...Object.keys(el)].includes(key))

console.log(resGet('-2'))
console.log(resGet('41dasd51asda5d1sd'))
```

Comment: Both objects in the question seem to be the same, just with keys printed in a different order, which means your result here might suffer the same fate simply because you cannot rely on the order of keys in an object.

Comment: data should be sorted by date

and then i want that out put in single object

Comment: @kevin What do you mean by a single object? It's a list. Are you saying you want the first created object? The last created object? It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want a _sorted object_ with the keys "in date order" of the original array. As explained in many comments already, _this is not possible_ as javascript does not guarantee the order, and when you print an object the order is usually alphabetical, but only because browsers decide to do that, it's not a feature of javascript. Therefor you cannot produce an object where keys are of a certain order. For order, there are `Array`s, like you have been using.

Comment: @somethinghere I'm sorry, I didn't notice his problem with his runtime autosorting it for him. I fixed my answer, does it fit now?